# String matching in Xtext

Tags: string, compare, match, xtext

it would be a pretty general question, but my search to an answer was unfortunately not a success.

What I want to know is, what would be the easiest approach to match two string objects in Xtext? I am almost sure, that this must be possible, but how? I was looking into Xbase to include this kind of a feature -if available- directly by extension into the DSL going to built by Xtext.

My starting point was, that I wanted to compare string attributes of two objects from certain model instances, by using EMFQuery. But EMFQuery doesn't directly support BooleanCondition in its WHERE, which could have been used with String.contains() or .regionMatches(); and the detour would be costly, since I intend to use EMFQuery only to test my conceptional model querying approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a language built on top of Xbase, you can simply use java.util.Pattern. Not sure I understood your question, though.

Comment: That's what I was going for. Sure with Xbase it is possible to use Java expression in your language. I wanted to know, if it could be done directly within Xtext.